# Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I have created a new service account and attached a custom role. This custom role has the `storage.buckets.get` permission. While using the new service account, I am still getting the following error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET [https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[bucket-name]?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false](https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/%5Bbucket-name%5D?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false): [service-account-name]@[project-id].iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

The python code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = os.getenv('BUCKET_NAME')
self.bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Roles of the service account:

```
ROLE
projects/[ProjectID]/roles/[CustomRole]
roles/storage.objectCreator
roles/storage.objectUser
roles/storage.objectViewer
roles/viewer
```

Permissions of `projects/[ProjectID]/roles/[CustomRole]` role:

```
description: [some-description]
etag: [some-etag]
includedPermissions:
- storage.buckets.get
name: projects/[ProjectID]/roles/[CustomRole]
stage: ALPHA
title: [Custom Role Title]
```

What could be the reason? I am making a query to get a particular bucket using this service account.

PS: I have waited 15 minutes and can confirm that the role is properly attached to the service account.

Comment: Please edit the question to show enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  Please include all the steps and code so we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Your code is using ADC yet you mention a service account. How are you setting up your code to use the service account? Does the service account mentioned in the error message match the service account permissions in your question? The error message wins, meaning the service account does not have the permissions you think it has OR the bucket name is incorrect/misspelled. Your question does not have the details we need to answer.

Comment: That bucket did not exist before me writing the code (didn't expect an authorization error to be the same on having or not having the permission and resource not existing). Now I know what the resource in "denied on resource" means. It's not a service account or a role (they are also resources), but the bucket resource. Shouldn't it be better to have a different error message in the two scenarios? If a resource has permissions to get a bucket, then the message should explicitly say that the resource does not exist?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghRai - Opinions vary due to security concerns. The goal is to minimize leaking information to hackers.